# Access values from proxy array in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am passing in a Proxy object of an array named "models" into this function. but i am not able to access whats inside the array.
In the terminal the output is like this:.

session output
Proxy(Array) {0: {…}}

session.models output undefined

I expected it to return the models array which is in the proxy object as i can see when do console.log(sesh)? Thats why I try to console.log the session.models

```
loadSessionObject(sesh) {
    if (sesh) {
        console.log("sesssion output", sesh);
    console.log("session.models output",sesh.models);
    return sesh.models ?? [];
    }

    return [];
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when u declare whatever variable gets passed in as sesh, use a ref()

```
// app.vue
import { ref } from 'vue'

const sesh = ref()
// now it will be reactive

// access properties like this:
console.log(sesh.value.models)
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

Comment: `sesh` is an array please provide more information about the function call